# Find the sum of the local minimums

Tags: calculus, functions

Find the sum of the local minimums

$$
f(x) = x^4-2x^3+x^2+1
$$

(original at https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkjKc.png)

Comment: Mathjaxed the math so that it can be searched.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. On this site, askers are expected to provide a bit of context along with their question, so please tell us a bit more. What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble? Do you understand how to find the local extrema of a function?

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to even start solving the problem

Comment: I don’t believe you. You must have _some_ idea of things to try. If you’ve read through the course material at all, you must’ve come across something about the derivative of the function and how it relates to local minima and maxima. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions) for some suggestion for ways to get started.

Comment: I know that the local minimums are (0,1) and (1,1), but how do I sum them?

Comment: just sum the $y$, minimum means the values of $f$ here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean the sum of the $x$ co-ordinates of the minimum:

$$\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= 4x^3-6x^2+2x \\
&= 2x(2x-1)(x-1)
\end{align*}$$

To find the stationary points, set this equal to zero. The $3$ possible solutions are therefore $0$, $1/2$ and $1$. However, as they asked for the minimums differentiate again.

$$f''(x) = 12x^2-12x+2$$

So $f''(0)= 2$ so that's a minimum (as it's greater than $0$).

$f''(0.5)= -1$ so that's a maximum (as that's smaller than $0$).

$f''(1)=2$ so that's also a minimum.

Therefore the sum of the minimums should be $0+2=2$.

I hope that helped.

Comment: You should learn how to use MathJax. There’s a quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: That is what I thought at first,

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what are the local minima of $f(x)-1$ ?

Comment: I can't see how this hint is at all useful.

Comment: well a perfect square with $2$ roots, they ought to be minima...

Comment: Aha, that's clever.